# How to set QGIS action to open and search for features on Google Maps?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, attribute-table, actions

At the moment, I have an action that takes each term in an address field and conducts a search on EACH term in Google (ie. multiple tabs are opened for each term). The action code I have is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=[% "ADDRESS1" %]
```

I would like to ask: what is the correct code to include ALL terms in the address field and, if possible, conduct a search on Google Maps instead of a simple Google search?

Comment: There is a Geocoder Plugin for QGIS https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/